# Having trouble with CollectionView in Xcode - display's black screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, collectionview

Basically I've been writing iOS apps for about 3 days (after reading a book to get the basic knowledge of design patterns and frameworks etc) and 1 entire day has been spent on this. I cannot get my `CollectionView` to display. I've got a storyboard that starts with a `TabBarView` and the two tabs (one is a `TableView` and the other is just a `UIView`) work, but the third tab (`UICollectionView`) just displays a black screen even after setting up.
How I set it up:

1) dragged a ViewController to the storyboard

2) made a relationship `segue` between my `UITabBarController` to the new `ViewController`

3) dragged a `UICollectionView` to the new `ViewController`

4) dragged 4 `UICollectionViewCell's` to the `CollectionView`

5) dragged 4 `UILabels` into said `CollectionViewCell's`

6) made a connection between the new `CollectionView's` delegate & data source and the header file of my `CollectionView` class (this might be where I went wrong, I did not make the connection to my `ViewController.h` class as I used this one for my `UITableView` and thought a new class was necessary)

7) declared the following methods in my `CollectionView.m` file

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//Populates each cell using the data given (no data in this case).
//Should return a CollectionViewCell.
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    //Gets the number of cells in each section.
    //Should return an integer value.
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    //Tells the collection view the number of sections it should have.
    //Should return an integer value.
    return 4;
}
```

I get the feeling there is something I missed out, as this logic makes sense to me as a programmer but, having such little experience in Xcode, maybe I forgot to link up this class to my `CollectionView` or something. Does anybody know where I went wrong?

BTW in case you're wondering, I'm using this CollectionView more of a navigation technique than to display wonderful images or anything, I am going to populate them with generic images later when they actually show up in the emulator.
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not displaying anything because default color of label is black, you'll have to change the color of text to any light color to see text over cell.

```
Now,
```

->Add a new file which should be subclass of **UICollectionViewCell**, Ctrl+drag from label to this class.(for eg I took  **mainViewCell**)and label property name I took **labelText**

->Declare reuseIdentifier for cell from Attribute Inspector,(mainCell, I took)

->Import cellClass to your **UIViewController** Class,

->Using this method to display any text

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    mainViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"mainCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.labelText.text = @"What-ever-you-want-display";
    return cell;
}
```

hope this would help...

Answer (score 0):

Did you tell your view controller(the one that contains the collection view) to use UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout?  For example,

```
@interface RootViewController () <UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource>
```

Also, have you set the reuse identifier for your cell?  In Interface Builder set this in the attributes inspector.  Then go to the cellForItemAtIndexPath: method and change this line to use your identifier.
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

Check out UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout in the documentation for methods used to size cells and set margins and spacing.

Answer (score 0):

The step 6) might be inadequate. Have you ctrl-dragged the collectionView to the controller icon beneath the main view directly? You would have been prompted in a black dialog box for connecting dataSource and delegate. The connections are made in XCode this way.
Alternatively you could explicitly set the dataSource as self in the controller implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Remove registerClass code from the default view controller code snippet

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
```